# Is "is when" acceptable while linking two objects or ideas?

Tags: grammar, phrases

In a grammar class I'm enrolled in, one of the diagnostic tests contained the following question:

> "Blocking" is when a television network schedules a less popular program between two popular ones

According to the test, a good revision would be:

> "'Blocking' is a television network's practice of scheduling a less popular program between two popular ones."

Why is it grammatically incorrect to connect two subjects with "is when" or "is how", as in the above example? My teacher called it an 'illogical expression.'

Are there any other "is *_*_" phrases that I should avoid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verb *to be* is a copular verb which is typically followed by an adjective or noun phrase as its complement:

> Blocking is common in modern television.
>
> Blocking is a common  television practice.

In your sentence the complement of the verb is a temporal clause starting with *when*. This is 'illogical' in the same way the following sentences are illogical:

> The test is next Wednesday.
>
> The test is when I decide you are ready to do it.

In fact, the test *takes place* or *will be scheduled for* next Wednesday or when I decide you are ready.

Similar constructions are:

> Cancer is why you shouldn't smoke.
>
> Practice is how you improve.

Careful writers may wish to avoid such constructions, but they are common. An example is the cartoon series "*Love is ..* ":

> Love is when he brings you breakfast in bed.

Comment: I can't accept 'The verb _to be_ is a copular verb which is typically followed by an adjective or noun phrase as its complement' here. A quick look at the AHD or Collins entries shows many other typical usages of _be_. _I am here_ where _be_ is followed by a locative is about as typical as it gets. (I'd say this is still a link-verb usage; the dictionaries disagree on this point.) Prepositional phrases may be used as complements of link verbs (_She stayed in the garden_), but I agree that the 'is when' construction sounds clumsy here - _The test is when I decide if you are ready_ is better.

Comment: @Edwin. I should have made it clearer that when the verb _to be_ has a _subject_ complement then this is typically a noun or adjective phrase. The perceived problem with the OP's sentence is that it has a temporal clause as its subject complement. But you are right that not all complements are subject complements.

Answer (score 2):

It is grammatically/ semantically incorrect (esp. in writing) because an important expression is omitted. There's ambiguity.

> 'Blocking' is (what happens/ that which takes place) when a television network schedules …

It does **not** mean the same thing as:

> 'Blocking' is a television network's practice of …

The first case refers to a **result** of an action, while the second correctly **defines** the action.

Omitting the expression as in your example can also cause the sentence to be interpreted as

> 'Blocking' is (what you do) when a television network schedules …

An instance of an action that is performed when a condition occurs.

Comment: Nice analysis - I'd just suggest _names_ rather than **defines**.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Now you put me in a bind! :) Is it *names*? Is it *defines*? The verbs run in opposite directions. 'Blocking' names, the clause following it 'defines', right? The purpose of the sentence could be to either define the term or name the action. The sentence can be used either way.